# Bad Alpha Channel when saving an image Externally

Tags: transparency

Really struggling with figuring this one out! I have some transparent/translucent materials I'd like to render on different passes. I am using some mask holdouts to get around misbehaving booleans for a faux "fluid sim" that involves filling a complex shape (deserves another post..) From the display inside Blender, they appear fine. However, when saving as a PNG, EXR, or multilayer EXR, the alpha channel is speckled.

Funnily enough, this is the same alpha I get when checking "convert premultiplied" in the compositor when I try using the alpha over node. Same speckled appearance when I have the alpha convert set to premultiplied. Note that I dont want to use the blender compositor for my final file export.

[image: Blender Viewer]

PNG viewer on file system or in After effects - tried all the alpha modes
[image: Exported PNG - notice the material on the right]

Same result when converting to premultiplied... interesting...
[image]

Result is OK with nothing in the node tree or with the alpha over node:
[image]
[image]

Blend - https://we.tl/t-ijQ126oytW
It just seems that blender's viewer is handling the alpha channel differently then when you try to save a file out of it. Thanks!

Comment: Noise is harder to see on the dark background - that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha channel is not denoised so it's noisy. You can use Denoise node to denoise only alpha and output it with File Output node. That's in Add -> Filter -> Denoise in the Compositor node editor.